# Handlebars Register Helpers - Sending values from model

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using a custom handlebars register helper to check conditional operators ( &&, ||, == ) and calling the register helper inside my each helper in my template backed by a model from Route.

But when I am passing the values from a model to the custom helper, the value is not passed to the helper instead the string as such is passed.

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
        {{#ifCond item '==' 'red'}}
            <li>{{item}}</li>
        {{/ifCond}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Route:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'pink'];
    }
});
```

ifCond Register Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (v1, operator, v2, options) {
    console.log(v1); //item - Here the value is coming as such and not the model value.
    console.log(v2);  // red
    console.log(operator); // ==
    console.log(options);
    switch (operator) {
    case '==':
        return (v1 == v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    case '===':
        return (v1 === v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    case '<':
        return (v1 < v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    case '<=':
        return (v1 <= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    case '>':
        return (v1 > v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    case '>=':
        return (v1 >= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    case '&&':
        return (v1 && v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    case '||':
        return (v1 || v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    default:
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

How do I pass the value from the model to the custom helper.

JSBin --> [Link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mifoy/3/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve object value you need to fetch it.

```
v1 = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, v1, options);
```

Comment: WOW great it is working fine thanks a lot. Can you just explain why I need to get the values from Ember.Handlebars instance.

Comment: First parameter this refers to the object to look up the property on.
Second parameter is the path to be lookedup.

As mentioned in api docs of ember
'Lookup both on root and on window. If the path starts with a keyword, the corresponding object will be looked up in the template's data hash and used to resolve the path.'